# C# Delete panels from Panel

Tags: c#, list, controls, panel

I need to make my panels to be removable from Panel. I need to be able to delete a specific panel from Panel:

1. panel is created once button "Create attribute" is clicked
2. Each Attribute has "contextmenustrip"
3. When "Delete" clicked it should delete a specific attribute.

Tried different scenarios but I was only able to remove only last created panel. Probably I should somehow use Lists?

*Don't be confused by the name of panel "Button" - in fact it is panel also...*
Here is method used to create panel(attribute) and insert it into Panel(attributes_panel). This method is executed from second Form once button clicked.

******************* Main Form ****************************

```
 int attributeTabIndex = 0;
    public PanelAttribute attribute;
    public void CreateNewFormAttribute()
    {

        //------- Creating Panel -------
        attribute = new PanelAttribute();
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
        Label attribute_label = new Label();
        attribute.TabIndex = attributeTabIndex;
        attribute.Name = "attribute" + attributeTabIndex.ToString();
        //------- Creating TextBox -------
        txtBox.Parent = attribute;
        txtBox.Size = new Size(attribute.Size.Width - 4, txtBox.Height);
        txtBox.Location = new Point(3, 25);
        //------- Creating Label -------
        attribute_label.Parent = attribute;
        attribute_label.Location = new Point(3, 5);
        attribute_label.Text = attribute.Name;
        //------- Inserting created "attribute" into "attributes_panel"
        mainPanelOfAttributes.Controls.Add(attribute);
        //------- Adding index increment -------
        attributeTabIndex++;
        //-------
    }
```

********************2nd Form**********************

```
  public void create_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_parentForm != null)
        {
            _parentForm.CreateNewFormAttribute();
        }
```

************* Adding ContextMenuStrip *******************

Performed in panel(as attribute) class

```
private void CreateNewOption()
    {
        AttributeOptions newAttributeOption = new AttributeOptions();
        this.ContextMenuStrip = newAttributeOption;
    }
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2usn2.jpg)

Comment: This is very confusing. You want to make panels removable from Panel? Also, can you show some code to make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, I want to make panels removable from Panel.

Comment: Can you show the code behind your example?

Comment: [Attributes in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) are a feature that allow you to describe properties of other objects. It does not sound like you're actually talking about C# Attributes. Consider re-wording your question to more accurately describe what you are trying to do.